# Stoplight system pulling information from multiple columns - how to set predence

Tags: list, column

I have created a stoplight system using the instruction below:

http://eimagine.com/creating-a-stoplight-color-coded-status-in-a-sharepoint-2013-list/

But want to expand it by pulling in information from other columns.  For example, the stoplight now looks at the calibration status of a piece of equipment.  I also have a column for third party inspection.  Can someone advise the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the technique recommended by Lukáš - and it works, but if you want OOB functionality use the Numeric Calculated Column Trick.

1. Add a list (or content type) a list or site column named "Color_Column" Type: Text.
2. Create a list column named "Status_Column".  Type: Calculated Column.  Output:  Numeric.
3. the evaluation of calculated columns in SharePoint is outputted as HTML.  if you google it, you can see it is actively being used by admins and users:  [link](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS749US749&q=sharepoint%20calculated%20column%20html&oq=sharepoint%20calculated%20column%20html)
4. Add the following formula to the [Status_Column]'s Calculated Column formula or something similar to it:

**="<div style='padding:10px;background-color:"&[Color_Column]&"  width:100%;height:100%; display:block;text-align:center;'>"{YOUR VALUE HERE}" </div>"**

Basically, if you are somewhat familiar with CSS and how to style output inline, you can create everything that Lukáš suggests, but out of the box.

---

EDIT

---

The above answer only applies to SharePoint ≤ 2013 *on-prem*.
SharePoint online will require Client side rendering, a page-level scripted solution (if appropriate), a third party solution, or some use of PerformancePoint (ugh).  I currently have a migration project that I need to convert prior to migration because this method is no longer supported in SPO.
Will update this post when I get to that particular migration project later this quarter!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend different technique - Client Side Rendering ([samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)). Using this technique the column will work in views and even in display form out-of-the-box. You don't have to add any webparts whatsoever.

Because this Client Side Rendering as the name suggests runs in a browser all columns used in the script (for conditions, calculations...) needs to be displayed in the view/form.